# ¿ como separar esta cadena de un DataFrame-Pandas,Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data

Buen día comunidad.

Actualmente ando realizando un Web scraping y una de las clases tiene  un string que tiene los caracteres con la siguiente salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como es un conjunto grandes de datos, como puedo separa la cadena de tal forma que queden las siguientes columnas:
8 habitaciones, 8 baños, 593/291 m2

Gracias

Comment: Cual es la pagina a la que le estás haciendo scraping? Con que modulo de Python lo estás haciendo?

Comment: Vendría genial que añadieses un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.